# Cannot import name Model in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pos-tagger

I'm using `hazm` in order to extract chunks in a text using `python 2.7` (Using an older version of python because of library compatibility)

In a line, I've to reference to a model called `postagger.model` as folows:

```
tagger = POSTagger(model='./resources/postagger.model')
```

But I get error: cannot import name Model

I have to mention that I have created resources folder and put `postagger.model` in the folder.

May you please help me what's wrong with my project?

Thank you

Update:
I've mentioned full traceback error message:

```
ImportError at /testCore1
cannot import name Model
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/testCore1?sentence=gre
Django Version: 1.11.29
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name Model
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\hazm\SequenceTagger.py in __init__, line 22
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python27.exe
Python Version: 2.7.15
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\newapp',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wapiti']
Server time:    Tue, 28 Apr 2020 05:10:01 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\user\Desktop\newapp\keywordextraction\views.py in testCore1
    tagger = POSTagger(model='resources/postagger.model') ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\hazm\SequenceTagger.py in __init__
        from wapiti import Model ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: The error message should have told you what line it's from. It sounds like it's not from the line you shared. It looks more like it's from an import statement, which is usually up at the top of a program. Can you share what your import statements look like, and what your Python files / folders are laid out?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you for your reply, I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error isn't in your code. hazm gives this error if you haven't installed WSL. See this issue on Github for more information:

https://github.com/sobhe/hazm/issues/144